# Error display on ajax form in rails not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using an inline form for users to submit data to a table (note that I'm using CSS rather than html tables to achieve this). When an error is returned by the verification in the model, I want to highlight the input field using the Bootstrap error class and put the error message below the appropriate form field. I'm using AJAX to submit the form.

I'm having problems, this is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
def create
@travel = Travel.new(params[:travel])
@travel[:user_id] = current_user.id
convert_date # and return

if @travel.save
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved trip"
  @travels = Travel.where("user_id = ?",current_user)
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
end
```

JS view:

```
<% if @travel.errors.any? %>
  <% @travel.errors.full_messages.each { |msg| logger.debug(msg) } %>
  <% @travel.errors.messages.each do |k,v| %>
  <% logger.debug("#tf_#{k}") %>
    $(<%= "#tf_#{k}" %>).insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<span class="control-group error"><span class="controls">");
    $(<%= "#tf_#{k}" %>).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","</span></span>");
    $(<%= "#error_#{k}" %>).val("<%= "#{k} #{v}" %>");
  <% end %> 
<%  else %>
  $(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
  $("#travels_list").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "travels") ) %>");
<%  end %>
```

form partial:

```
<%= form_for @travel, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "form-inline", :id => "new-travel-form"} do |f| %>
<div class="row-fluid">
<span id="tf_city"><%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => "London, UK", :class => "span3" %></span>
<span id="tf_arrive_date"><%= f.text_field :arrive_date, :class => "span2" %> </span>
<span id="tf_leave_date"><%= f.text_field :leave_date, :class => "span2" %> </span>
<span id="tf_notes"><%= f.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "e.g. staying at the Hilton", :class => "span3" %></span>
<%= f.submit "save", :class => "btn btn-primary span1" %>
</div>
<% end %> 

<div class="row-fluid error" id="error_expl">
<span id="error_city" class="help-inline span3"></span>
<span id="error_arrive_date" class="help-inline span2"></span>
<span id="error_leave_date" class="help-inline span2"></span>
<span id="error_notes" class="help-inline span3">test</span>

</div>
```

The `logger.debug` in the JS is firing, so I know that the error is getting passed to the JS, but the `insertAdjacentHMTL()` doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not going to answer your question but i hope it could help to improve your code.

First, according to your code i guess you should have some associations like this in the model User:

```
has_many :travels
```

And in your model Travel:

```
belongs_to :user
```

So, in order to improve your code you can have this in your controller:

```
respond_to :js, only: [:create]

def new
 @travel = current_user.travels.new
end

def create
 @travel = current_user.travels.new(params[:travel])
 if @travel.save
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved trip"
   @travels = current_user.travels
 else
   # I guess you should have some code here in case any validation fail. If you dont 
   # have validations for the model Travel, you don't need the if statement here.
 end
end
```

About your problem, can you clarify what is `"#tf_#{k}"`?